# Is the current density ${\bf j}$ an observable?

Tags: electric-current, superconductivity

The current density ${\bf j}$ is most easily defined from$$ I = \int_{\text{cross-section} \atop \text{of wire}} \textbf{j}\cdot d\textbf{S}, $$ where $I$ is the current flowing through the wire.
From this formula nothing seems to be suggesting that ${\bf j}$ is not an observable.

BUT, consider the London equation, in the context of superconductors: $$ \textbf{j} = -\frac{n_s e^2}{m_e}\textbf{A}, $$ where $n_s$ is the number density of superconducting electrons, $m_e$ their mass and $\bf{A}$ the magnetic vector potential.

As it is well-known, the magnetic vector potential is **not** an observable and in fact subject to a further degree of freedom which is fixed by a gauge choice.

From the equality of ${\bf j}$ to ${\bf A}$, it would seem that the current density shares the vector potential's property of not being an observable.

Comment: The London equation you wrote down holds only in Coulomb gauge. You've already made your gauge choice.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I haven't seen the derivation, but don't you still have some gauge freedom in Coulomb gauge?

Comment: No, afaik, the Coulomb gauge has no residual gauge freedom.

Comment: If $\mathbf A$ vanishes at infinity, then $\nabla\times \mathbf A$ and $\nabla\cdot \mathbf A$ determine $\mathbf A$ uniquely.

Comment: The London's equation are in fact $\nabla\times\Lambda j_{s}=-B$ and $\partial\Lambda j_{s}=E$ which are gauge-invariant, with $\Lambda$ a phenomenological length, called the London's (penetration) length. $j_{s}$ is the superconducting current, and the total current $j=j_{n}+j_{s}$ is the sum of the normal and superconducting current in general. This is sufficient to show perfect diamagnetism, Meissner effect and so on. I think you can show that $j\propto A$ in the case of the Coulomb gauge, as @ACuriousMind suggested.

Comment: By the way, I made a small mistake, as you did actually. What I wrote and what you wrote are not London's equation, but London's CONSTITUTIVE RELATIONS.